# NullPointerException while mockStatic if preceding whenNew

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have following test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({BuildCcHeaderProcess.class, IOUtils.class})
public class MyTest {
...
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
          ...
          whenNew(StringWriter.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(stringWriterMock);
          PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class); //exception throws here
          ....
     }
     ....
}
```

When I invoke the test I see following result:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor23.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:100)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
    at com.MyTest.setUp(MyTest.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.<init>(Writer.java:71)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:75)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:62)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:113)
    ... 37 more
```

What do I wrong?

If to remove following row:

```
whenNew(StringWriter.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(stringWriterMock);
```

code becomes working...

What the magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown when the static initializer of `IOUtils` is executed, which looks like this (version 2.4):

```
static {
    // avoid security issues
    StringBuilderWriter buf = new StringBuilderWriter(4);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(buf); //<-- kaboom here
    out.println();
    LINE_SEPARATOR = buf.toString();
    out.close();
}
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown down the stack while invoking `new PrintWriter(buf)` because the parameter (`buf`) is null.

I suspect your remaining test code modifies the code so that `buf` is assigned a value of `null`. Did you mock the Constructor of `StringBuilderWriter` for some reason?

Comment: Thus I can just swap 2 rows!

Comment: Which 2 rows are you talking about? My guess is simply that the rest of your mocking messes up the inner workings of the IOUtils initializer. Debugging might help to check at which point the ``null`` value is introduced.